# How do I mapping usb storage device path to physicaldrive?

Tags: c++, windows, usb, driver

I get the usb device path from

```
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()
```

and I can get the device path such like

```
\\?\usbstor#disk&ven_&prod_2307_pram&......
```

but I want to map device path to physical drvie

```
->  \\physicaldrive0,1,2......
```

or inverse I can map physical drvie to device path
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, I found it.
put the HANDLE into DeviceIoControl and use IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER

```
STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER number;   //use this to get disk numbers
DWORD readed;                   // discard results
BOOL result = DeviceIoControl(
    hdl,                // handle to device
    IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, // dwIoControlCode
    NULL,                            // lpInBuffer
    0,                               // nInBufferSize
    &number,           // output buffer
    sizeof(number),         // size of output buffer
    &readed,       // number of bytes returned
    NULL      // OVERLAPPED structure
);
```

and the number.DeviceNumber is the PhysicalDrive number